# How to combine multiple files into one file?

Tags: sequence-alignment, phylogenetics, phylogeny, bash

I have multiple files (n=86000) with one column each and I want to combine them all into one file with 86000 columns.

I tried the following command

```
Paste *.txt > mean.txt
```

And as a for loop

```
for i in *.txt, do paste $i > mean.txt; done
```

This did not appear to work because there are 86000 to combine, I then divided my files into multiple folders with each folder not containing more than 15000 files but this did not working

Format of my single file is as follows (It has 16000 lines)

```
0.047202943506056
0.0383549703366668
0.0159162908608477
0.0238048058550539
0.0694728928685859
0.0389052658410832
```

What is the bug in the code?

Comment: Thanks. Do you want one long list? In this case the command is 'cat' not 'paste'. Just check you are not  exceeding your disk space.

Comment: What is the error message you get?

Comment: Equivalently answered here assuming OP wants to concatenate vertically, not horizontally, though the approach could be modified anyway: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18695105/how-to-concatenate-huge-number-of-files

Comment: Re-reading the question: 16000 lines x 86000 files ... this is not alot. I think the error report is important, or else perhaps it just hangs?

Comment: @ Fabio Marroni There is no error. When I check the output file it has only one column.

Comment: @Michael: No don't want one long list. I want an output file with 86000 columns.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about bioinformatics but file manipulation. In any case it has been answered [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/205642/combining-large-amount-of-files).

Comment: @Priya The fact that you wanted a file with 86000 columns is not clear from your original post. You simply said you wanted to combine them into a single file. When posting questions, please take time to clearly and precisely describe the issue.

Comment: @DanielStandage Apologies for not being clear but I have not got my answer yet.

Comment: @Priya Please explain what is not clear from the thread I linked in my first comment.

Comment: @DanielStandage Sorry, I didn't click the link in your post. Thank you

Comment: @DanielStandage such questions [are on topic](https://bioinformatics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/88/298) since manipulating and parsing text files is a very large part of a bioinformatician's work. This question is really not clear, mind you, but it is on topic.

Comment: @Priya  tried to clarify the question a bit and I also suspected a typo in the code you tried. I hope the edits I have done are appropriate, if not please roll it back or [edit] it by your own :-).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bug in your loop appears be "`> filename`" per column, this over-rides the last iteration resulting in a file with a single column, which has been over-written 85999 times. Thus the file output you observe should be the single column present in the last file of your array. If you replaced "`> filename`" with "`>> filename`" within the loop you would then append to the file a new column with each iteration. If the loop fell over at some point you could then simply use one of the outputs of `wc filename` to assess how many columns you had (you might have to transponse the data for wc to work (lots of scripts for this in Perl), although there will almost certainly be an easy solution for counting columns in awk.

Personally, I would use a dataframe for this operation (possibly R, definately Python pandas), because 86000 columns is a lot of columns in any other walk of life, even if it is just post-processing. Generally, if you just want bash, awk is a better solution in this case (I don't code with it, but some here certainly do). However, I do get the idea that `paste` will work if each column is an identical length.

BTW `paste` must be lower case, you've got `Paste` in the first line of your code, but its okay in the second bit of code.

BTW BTW, I did not know shell would take *.txt directly as an array, with Perl/Python you need to "glob" it and assign it as an array/list.